How to add a wave effect to reach native component
I have made this component which should serve as my loader and I needed to make it have a loading wavelike effect, below is the component and also an image of it
export const Item = (props) =>{
  const {height, width, bgColor, br} = props
  return(
    <View style={styles.item(height, width, bgColor, br)}></View>
  )
}



What do you mean with wave-effect?

@Michael Bahl thanks for your reply, I mean like skeleton-loading effect

There are several modules for that available, i.e. https://github.com/enzomanuelmangano/animate-with-reanimated/tree/main/18-skeleton-animation
